# Unable to start pritunl after installation

Tags: python, mongodb, centos, vps

I've installed pritunl on my VPS. Now I can't access to the web interface. It's not possible to start the service (Please have a look on the logs below).
There's a mariadb DB besides the mongodb which is included in pritunl, is it a problem? (I need the mariadb for other applications, thats why)
I followed the official guide for CentOS. It seems like there are some missing prerequisites, but actually I don't know.
Can someone help me out? :-)

Thanks!
Moejoe

```
pritunl logs
[undefined][2017-01-30 21:45:51,211][ERROR] Pritunl setup failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pritunl/setup/__init__.py", line 68, in setup_db
    setup_mongo()
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pritunl/setup/mongo.py", line 65, in setup_mongo
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS=MONGO_SOCKET_TIMEOUT,
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 345, in __init__
    seeds.update(uri_parser.split_hosts(entity, port))
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 244, in split_hosts
    raise ConfigurationError("Empty host "
ConfigurationError: Empty host (or extra comma in host list).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pritunl", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pritunl==1.26.1231.99', 'console_scripts', 'pritunl')()
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pritunl/__main__.py", line 264, in main
    setup.setup_db()
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pritunl/setup/__init__.py", line 68, in setup_db
    setup_mongo()
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pritunl/setup/mongo.py", line 65, in setup_mongo
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS=MONGO_SOCKET_TIMEOUT,
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 345, in __init__
    seeds.update(uri_parser.split_hosts(entity, port))
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 244, in split_hosts
    raise ConfigurationError("Empty host "
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Empty host (or extra comma in host list).
```

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem.
The only solution is to (temporaly) shut down apache:

Obviously `sudo service httpd stop` or on debian `sudo service apache stop`

After that, you should be able to finish the installation and start pritunl, and change the ports to not use 80 and 443, and finally restarting everything like a boss

For me that was like, in this order only

```
sudo pritunl set app.redirect_server false
sudo service pritunl stop
sudo service apache start 
sudo service pritunl start
```